# Add class to a table colum

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with three columns and need to access the third column. I have to check  If the items in this column have country as a value and if it's true add a class.

How can I do it without jQuery?

Comment: add class attribute to the 3rd td tag of each row. You can then use DOM to get the elements by class and check their values

Comment: Why do you need a class? If you could target the third column with now class in the css would that work too?

Comment: Table rows have an index starting from zero. Table cells also have an index within their row, starting from zero. So the 3rd column in the first row would be `tableRef.rows[0].cells[2]`, and so on for the 3rd cell in each row. But likely there is a selector that will get them as a collection. You might consider adding a *colgroup* element.

Comment: The thing is that the table generate dynamically since i'm using a crud generator. so depending on the <td> value i should add a class. if is country one class if is a city another class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)**, with `td:nth-child(3)` as the selector to grab the third cell of each row.

Iterate through the collection, adding the class when the cell's **[textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)** is not empty:

```js
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(3)');

for(var i = 0 ; i < cells.length ; i++) {
  if(cells[i].textContent.trim() > '') {
    cells[i].classList.add('present');
  }
}
```

```css
.present {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><th>First name</th><th>Last name<th>Country
  <tr><td>Thomas    </td><td>Doe      </td><td>Australia</td>
  <tr><td>Richard   </td><td>Webster  </td><td>         </td>
  <tr><td>Harold    </td><td>Hooligan </td><td>USA      </td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>Poland</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here you can traverse through all of the rows and get the 3rd columns innerHTML to be manipulated further

```
var rowLength = document.getElementById('table').rows.length;
 for(var i = 0;i<rowLength;i++){
   console.log(document.getElementById('table').rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fun way, https://jsfiddle.net/c259LrpL/1/

```
var t = document.getElementById("table");
var trs = t.getElementsByTagName("td");
var tds = null;

for (var i=0; i<trs.length; i++)
{
    tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (var n=0; n<trs.length;n++)
    {
        if ((n+1) %3 == 0){
        trs[n].classList.add("new_class");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
  <table id='mytable'>
    <tr>
      <td class="first">Name</td>
      <td class="second">Occupation</td>
      <td class="third">Country</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="first">Name</td>
      <td class="second">Occupation</td>
      <td class="third"></td> <!-- empty -->
    </tr>  
    <tr>
      <td class="first">Name2</td>
      <td class="second">Occupation2</td>
      <td class="third">Country2</td>
    </tr>  
  </table>
```

Javascript

```
  var Elements = document.getElementById("mytable").getElementsByClassName("third");

    alert(Elements.length);
  for (var i=0; i < Elements.length; i++) {
    if (Elements[i].textContent != "") {
      alert(Elements[i].textContent + " adding class");
            Elements[i].className += "new";
    }
  }
```

CSS

```
.new {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/codeforwin/scyw2by0/